# Не складываются маленькие числа

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Дело в том что нужно складывать маленькие числа, такие как 0.0000038625. При сложении получаю 7.725E-6. Если возвожу через функцию exp() возводится неправильно. Получается не 0 целых, а 1 целая, да и само значение немного не правильное.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/book.gmp.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Для данного примера:

```
$first = 0.0000038625;

$second = 0.0000038625;

$result = $first + $second;

echo number_format($result, 9);

// или

printf("%0.9f", $result);
```

Вместо 9 можно подставить переменную, определив, сколько знаков после запятой содержится в результате $result (пример см. в мануале по вышеприведенной ссылке).

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13366697/php-display-small-floating-number-as-it-is

Answer (score 1):

Тип `float` в PHP [не гарантирует сохранение точности числа](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.float.php).

Если вам необходимо работать с величинами произвольной точности, то можно использовать [расширение GMP](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.gmp.php) или [расширение BC Math](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.bc.php)